# Cryptic Crossword #4: Build Your Own Crossword

Tags: crosswords, cryptic-crosswords

*Note: This isn't an ordinary cryptic crossword, but it's certainly cryptic, and it's certainly a crossword, so I've adorned it with the title anyways.*

---

[image: Crossword grid]

### Across

1. *A fishy complaint,

    A covering sheet,

    A pack ox's burden,

    A sour, sweet treat.*

3. *A big, furry mammal,

    A bubble of water,

    A term of endearment,

    A term for the slaughtered.*

5. *An Islamic official,

    A Baldur's Gate ranger,

    Popular women,

    Spiritual chambers.*

6. *An Italian actress,

    A dry, hard bread,

    A deceptive plot,

    Means darkness ahead.*

8. *To a smaller extent,

    Where one might be flappin',

    A monster's abode,

    For fear it should happen.*

10. *A place to play darts,

     A piece least elite,

     Unbreakable rules,

     Two small, furry feet.*

12. *An Iron Age Hallstatt,

     A room in a ward,

     A ring-a-ding thing,

     A flexible cord.*

14. *Shots past the target,

     Direct nowhere near,

     Alleges with poise,

     Incredibly clear.*

15. *Islamic religion,

     A hooved, woodland creature,

     To once have been viewed,

     A prophetic preacher.*

16. *Sensory helpers,

     A mountainous lake,

     Feathers' ancestor,

     A way you can make.*

### Down

1. *A super descriptor,

    A frivolous sin,

    Adhered by a band,

    To gradually thin.*

2. *A very short moment,

    A thing you might play,

    A poke with a needle,

    A thing you might pay.*

3. *A slow, prolonged accent,

    An unstructured scuffle,

    Sketched with a pencil,

    Impeccable muscle.*

4. *Fasten together,

    Alternative turf,

    Rends from the bone,

    Goes under the surf.*

7. *Killed, as a dragon,

    A gradual pace,

    A mix of ingredients,

    To put in its place.*

9. *A brief, reddish glow,

    Complete lack of sweat,

    The edge of a rooftop,

    With or, makes a threat.*

10. *Parts of a sneaker,

     Interrelated,

     Walks back and forth,

     Measured or rated.*

11. *A male, Slavic title,

     To zero amount,

     Divide into parts,

     A continental count.*

12. *A purposeful capsule,

     Afflicted by bane,

     Suddenly broken,

     A vocal disdain.*

13. *A Caribbean dwarf,

     Things touching the plate,

     Flax fiber fabric,

     Places to wait.*

Comment: Go for the eyes, boo! Go for the eyes!

Comment: I can solve the clues but the answers can't all fit at once or I have to have four separate puzzles or the answers aren't words. Should they be? Is there an extra step?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK title, my friend! :) it's like a choose your own adventure.

Comment: Okay. That sounds like a lot of work. I'll let someone else do it ;-)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put into these. Thanks!

Comment: Dang, I was thinking of the wrong ranger with a 5 letter name.

Comment: Brilliant as usual!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The twist here is:

> Two cells of each answer can contain one of two letters, giving a total of four possible solutions per clue

Completed grid:

> [image: Image of solved puzzle]

**Across**

1. A fishy complaint

> CARP - To complain as well as a type of fish

A covering sheet

> TARP - Short for tarpaulin

A pack ox's burden

> CART - An ox might pull a cart

A sour, sweet treat.

> TART - A desert (sweet treat) as well as meaning sour

3. A big, furry mammal,

> BEAR

A bubble of water,

> BEAD

A term of endearment,

> DEAR

A term for the slaughtered.

> DEAD

5. An Islamic official,

> DIVAN - Can be a title applied to [high officials in the Middle East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewan#Title)

A Baldur's Gate ranger,

> KIVAN - The name of a ranger in Baldur's Gate

Popular women,

> DIVAS - A term used for popular female singers

Spiritual chambers.

> KIVAS - A kiva is [a room used by Puebloans for religious rituals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiva)

6. An Italian actress,

> DUSE - Eleonora Duse was [an Italian actress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleonora_Duse)

A dry, hard bread,

> RUSK

A deceptive plot,

> RUSE

Means darkness ahead.

> DUSK - The period before night time

8. To a smaller extent,

> LESS

Where one might be flappin',

> NEST - A bird might be flapping in a nest

A monster's abode,

> NESS - Loch Ness is the home of the Loch Ness monster

For fear it should happen.

> LEST - Meaning for fear of something undesirable happening

10. A place to play darts,

> LAWN - Darts can be played on a lawn (although I prefer the pub)

A piece least elite,

> PAWN - Generally the least powerful piece in chess

Unbreakable rules,

> LAWS

Two small, furry feet.

> PAWS

12. An Iron Age Hallstatt,

> CELT - Hallstatt was an Iron Age Celtic culture

A room in a ward,

> CELL

A ring-a-ding thing,

> BELL

A flexible cord.

> BELT

14. Shots past the target,

> OVERS - Having gone past the target, one has overshot

Direct nowhere near,

> AVERT - to ward off

Alleges with poise,

> AVERS - To allege as a fact

Incredibly clear.

> OVERT

15. Islamic religion,

> DEEN - A term [loosely associated with Islamic religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABn)

A hooved, woodland creature,

> DEER

To once have been viewed,

> SEEN

A prophetic preacher.

> SEER

16. Sensory helpers,

> EARS

A mountainous lake,

> TARN - [A mountain lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarn_(lake))

Feathers' ancestor,

> TARS - Comes before feathers in the phrase 'tar and feather'

A way you can make.

> EARN - To make money

**Down**

1. A super descriptor,

> CAPED - As in 'Batman: The Caped Crusader'

A frivolous sin,

> CAPER - A frowned upon activity that is nevertheless fairly harmless

Adhered by a band,

> TAPED

To gradually thin.

> TAPER

2. A very short moment,

> TRICE

A thing you might play,

> TRICK - You might play a trick on someone

A poke with a needle,

> PRICK

A thing you might pay.

> PRICE - You might pay the price

3. A slow, prolonged accent,

> DRAWL

An unstructured scuffle,

> BRAWL

Sketched with a pencil,

> DRAWN

Impeccable muscle.

> BRAWN

4. Fasten together,

> RIVET

Alternative turf,

> DIVET - Alternative spelling of divot

Rends from the bone,

> RIVES - To split or tear apart violently

Goes under the surf.

> DIVES

7. Killed, as a dragon,

> SLEW - One slays a dragon

A gradual pace,

> SLOW

A mix of ingredients,

> STEW

To put in its place.

> STOW

9. A brief, reddish glow,

> ELVE - [A reddish glow seen over a thunderstorm](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/elve)

Complete lack of sweat,

> EASE - E.g. done with ease, without having to try

The edge of a rooftop,

> EAVE

With or, makes a threat.

> ELSE - As in 'or else'

10. Parts of a sneaker,

> LACES

Interrelated,

> LACED

Walks back and forth,

> PACES

Measured or rated.

> PACED

11. A male, Slavic title,

> NEVEN - [A Slavic masculine name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neven)

To zero amount,

> NEVER - As in something that never happens happens zero amount of times

Divide into parts,

> SEVER

A continental count.

> SEVEN - The number of continents, by most standards

12. A purposeful capsule,

> BURSE - [A pouch or case for some special purpose](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/burse)

Afflicted by bane,

> CURST - Alternative spelling of cursed

Suddenly broken,

> BURST

A vocal disdain.

> CURSE

13. A Caribbean dwarf,

> TINEN - [A Haitian Creole word for dwarf](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/haitian-creole-word-dc3cf8c97c117b5bf4840be2b2294d161861c3d3.html) (struggling by this stage were you?!)

Things touching the plate,

> TINES - The tines or prongs of a fork might touch a plate

Flax fiber fabric,

> LINEN

Places to wait.

> LINES

Comment: Not a lot of overlap in words starting with 'T' and 'N' and ending with 'N' and 'S', yaknow? :) Good job!

Comment: Also, .I.A. does not match a ton of words, let me tell ya.